# What is the difference between "way of thinking" vs "the way they think"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I am writing a short description of a social experiement. The objective is to get a better idea of the way people think. 
I have some troubles to understand the difference between those two phrases:

1. To encounter people and better understand their way of thinking
2. To encounter people and better understand the way they think

Is there any difference in meaning between those two phrases? If so, could you please tell me what their are?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: _The way they think_ is a completely different construction from _the way to think_. And both are different from _their way of thinking_. So what, exactly, is your question? Do you want a structural analysis, a semantic analysis, or a pragmatic analysis? And of which constructions?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @JohnLawlerinexile! I am looking for a semantic analysis between "way of thinking" and "way they think"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Way of thinking*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/british/Ways-of-thinking) typically refers to someone's perspective or viewpoint, e.g., "It's a good plan, by my way of thinking."

*The way they think* uses the definition of [*way*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way) that means "how someone does something," so the phrase would refer to the method or practice that people use to think. For example, the way one person thinks might be by carefully analyzing the facts, while the way another person thinks might be to jump to conclusions.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get the difference. It's maybe because I am French and we don't have this disctinction. According to you link "way of thinking" can also be use to  describe "a particular way of thinking about or dealing with something" which seems to me to correspond to your explanation of "the way they think". Which one would best describe the different way people from different culture think? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It depends. If you're talking about, say, what French people in general think about a certain topic, _way of thinking_ would be best because you're talking about French people's perspective or viewpoint on the matter. If you're describing something like how people from Culture X tend to be more detail-oriented in their thinking while people from Culture Y tend to take a more holistic approach, then you would use _the way they think_ because you're talking about the method that they use to think.

Comment: If I get it in the right way "way of thinking" is close to "opinion" and "the way they think" is could be related to "a method of thinking". Is that right?

Comment: Why do you assume there has to be a meaning difference? To most English speakers, the two phrases are just different ways to say the same thing. When this happens (as it does with any option in English, of which there are millions), somebody is bound to say that they mean different things to them. Which is true. The problem is that different people find different "meanings", and there is no agreement. As perhaps you are alresdy finding out. As to which one to use, use the one you prefer, for whatever reasons you prefer. That's what everybody else does.

Answer (score 0):

The "way of thinking" is the lens you see through allowing bias and belief to influence how you see something. Cultural views show this. Ie. How Americams views themselves vs how the French see Americans.

The "way you think" are the actions of deduction you choose to use to counteract or cement "the way of thinking" you feel most comfortable with or/and meets your objectives.

We use both. It's like I may think culturally all Americans are loud blow hard bullies yet meeting them individually I know the majority are generous, giving, curious, fun loving people.

I don't know if this is correct but this is how these terms feel to me and through my way of seeing and investigation.

Comment: How do we get our lens to show us more truth? By refining how we think to lessen the way of thinking influencing us. A process?

Comment: Your answer works. It would show as a stronger answer if you remove the last sentence, which says that your analysis is more personal opinion than authoritative answer.